# Filtering Dataframe on String Datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has one of the columns with string data type. I am trying to apply filetring on that column and write the filtered output as a csv.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx',sheet_name=['Site Data'])
df1=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['TM Cell ID','Milestone Achieved','Site Type'])
df1['Milestone Achieved']=df1['Milestone Achieved'].astype('string')

df2=df1.loc[df1['Milestone Achieved']=="MS13"]
df2.to_csv('MS13.csv',index=False)
```

It generating a blank csv file and i do not get the desired output. This is the input :

[image]

I am expecting to see:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `df1['Milestone Achieved']=df1['Milestone Achieved'].str.strip()` instead `df1['Milestone Achieved']=df1['Milestone Achieved'].astype('string')`

Comment: Thanks, tried but same result.

Comment: I see another problem, replace `df1=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['TM Cell ID','Milestone Achieved','Site Type'])` to `df1=df[['TM Cell ID','Milestone Achieved','Site Type']].copy()`

Comment: thanks, now getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

    df1=df[['TM Cell ID','Milestone Achieved','Site Type']].copy()
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'